# Weird Large Title Navigation Controller issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

## Problem

[I am having this problem](https://i.imgur.com/OIOifBN.gif). It only happens when I am not on the top of the table view. When I am on the top, no problem at all.

• I have tried this on a real device too, but no luck.

• I thought shadow behind the cell might causing it but removing it didn't work either.

• It works just fine without a large title but I want to implement large title function too.

I show the `secondViewController` without programmatically. But to go back to `firstViewController` I use this code:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Are you using iOS 11

Comment: Yes I am using iOS 11 but never had this issue with other large titles before. Still found a solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/46742977/7043190

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem!

Setting the background color to the white on the `secondViewController` fixed the problem.

Add this to `secondViewController` in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white }
```